# How to update tags of Elastic Beanstalk environment with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an elastic beanstalk environment created with CloudFormation. Now I've added an additional tag and value but during the update of the stack I get:

```
Elastic Beanstalk environment tags cannot be updated.
```

Is there a way to fix this? I don't want to delete the environment and bring it back up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to AWS documentation for [Cloudformation ElasticBeanstalk Environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk-environment.html), for `Tags` we have the following update policy:

> Update requires: You can update tags only if you update another
>   property that requires that the environment be replaced, such as the
>   ApplicationName property.

Which means you **cannot** update tags without rebuilding the environment using cloudformation.

However, you can update tags outside of cloudformation stack - 
[Tagging Resources in Your Elastic Beanstalk Environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.tagging.html):

> You can specify tags when you create the Elastic Beanstalk
>   environment. In an existing environment, you can add or remove tags,
>   and you can update the values of existing tags. In addition to the
>   default tags, you can add up to 47 additional tags to each
>   environment.

Be careful, as changing stack resources outside of cloudformation is not recommended and may lead to [Cloudformation stack drift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-drift.html)

Comment: The CloudFormation ElasticBeanstalk Environment Tags have recently been improved so that "Update requires: No interruption". We should now be able to update tags without rebuilding the Environment.

Comment: Looks like the improvement was only not showing the message, some of our stacks are not getting the Tags and not throwing errors.